# Visual Fox Pro, ODBC - I can't see .DBF tables in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-foxpro

I'm making integration with application that is using ODBC Data Source - Visual Fox Pro Driver. In its dirrectory structure I've got two dirrectories (DANE and TRANS) which contains .DBF files. When I am using Visual Studio 2010 Server Explorer -> Data Connections to connect to DATA .DBF files, everything work fine. The problem occurs when I'm trying to use TRANS dirrectory - I don't see any tables (When I am using DBF Viewer - there are around 30-40 tables). When I try to connect to them using connection strings :

```
Provider=vfpoledb;Dsn=Visual FoxPro Tables;Data source=c:\Softech\G_POS\DANE
Provider=vfpoledb;Dsn=Visual FoxPro Database;Data source=c:\Softech\G_POS\TRANS
```

I can get data from DANE without problem. On TRANS I can connect to database, but I've god exception when I try to get data (OleDbException) - Can't read file c:\Softech\G_POS\TRANS\"name of table".dbf
Norbert

---

"Visual FoxPro Database" is abstract name of destination. That's not a database, just my custom name of data source

Answer (score 1):

The problem comes from the DSN specified.  The default "Visual FoxPro Database" ODBC Data Source assumes a Database Container (DBC) is specified in the Data Source or SourceDB attributes.  This equates to the [SourceType](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/167405) attribute, as in SourceType=DBC.

You should switch to using the "Visual FoxPro Tables" DSN or appending the filename for the DBC to the Data Source attribute.

Also, according to the [Foxpro Ole Db documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/3haz2895%28v=VS.80%29.aspx), you should either use "Data Source" or DSN but not both.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a dumb answer,

Your connection strings are not equal. You use "Database" in the second connection string but your'e talking about tables..

Greatz