# How to: read/write Dbase III files (.dbf) C# VS 2010 using Visual FoxPro OLE DB Driver

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, dbf

I have been unable to find any complete example or guide to use Visual FoxPro OLD DB driver with Visual Studio 2010 to read and write data to/from .DBF files.

I found some info for VS 2005 but it doesnt seem to work w/ VS2010.

When I open Server Explorer and try to add a new Data Connection, the Visual FoxPro Driver is not listed.

Based on reading and searching for several days now it appears that this driver is the best way to go for handling DBF's but I am not necessarily tied to it=  I am open to ANY solid, fast solution.

Any direction most appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3787261/visual-fox-pro-odbc-i-cant-see-dbf-tables-in-visual-studio-2010)?

Comment: Doesn't work on my machine anymore either.  You'll need to invoke a time machine, ask how at superuser.com

Comment: Are you still pending on getting connected with VFP via OleDB?

Answer (score 1):

Install [VFPOLEDB provider](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=14839), and then you'll be able to connect to DBF files.

Answer (score 0):

Your could create a Linked Server to this Foxpro Database from SQL Server. That will make the Foxpro data accessible.